# Iterating through a tuple in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm currently trying to iterate through a tuple which is stored in a list and print out the first 3 elements. It works initially however it then prints out the first index another 3 times and I have no idea why. The following code:

```
if user_choice == "b":
    for x in holiday_database:       
        for i in x:
            if x.index(i) == 0:            
                print("\nPackage ", i)
            if x.index(i) == 1:
                print("Country: ", i)
            if x.index(i) == 2:
                print("City: ", i)
```

outputs this:

```
Package  1
Country:  france
City:  paris

Package  1

Package  1

Package  1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for your problem?

Comment: Also, since you are always checking against `x.index(i)`, it will make more sense to wrap the whole thing in one `if` block instead of three.  Or just use a `list` to return the names.

Comment: Yea I can. The data inside the tuple?

Comment: yeah, just show us some input that produced that output for example

Comment: It would help to see a sample of what `holiday_database` look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to loop over the tuple at all. Use string formatting. Tuples are already the data type used for string formatting arguments, so all you need to do is slice the tuple.

```
if user_choice == "b":
    for x in holiday_database:       
        print('\nPackage %d\nCountry: %s\nCity: %s' % x[:3])
```

This assumes that the `Package` (i.e. `x[0]`) is of `int` data type. If it's a `str` then just change the `%d` to another `%s`.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question though.  What if `holiday_database` actually looks like `[(1, 'france', 'paris'), (1, ), (1, ), (1, )]` which created the output? Your code would return a `TypeError`.  It helps to clarify the unknown before hastily tossing an answer into the ring.

Comment: This happened to work perfectly, thanks. I also should have supplied more information with the original question, apologies.

Comment: @Idlehands I suppose I was assuming that the tuples were guaranteed to have all three values needed. I'll ask OP whether that is a safe assumption.

Comment: @Rorzy Please see above comment.

Comment: @mypetlion yea, the first 3 values of each tuple are required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is the data; it would produce the result above if *holiday_database* is *[(1, "france", "paris"), (1,), (1,), (1,)]*

However you can rewrite the code much more concisely in a number of ways. I suggest tuple unpacking:

```
for record in holiday_database:
    package_num, country, city = record
    print("\nPackage:", package_num)
    print("Country:", country)
    print("City:", city)
```

This works because *package_num, country, city* is itself a tuple expression, so python can match each variable with the data. This will throw an error if the tuple is not the correct size.

Comment: In cases of tuples with not enough values, `(1,)` in your example, this will give you a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`. All you've done is move the error to a different line.

Comment: True, and I think I made that clear myself. Nevertheless it's always good to write code as simply as possible and it is better if an error in your data results in an exception than nonsensical output.